# Angular2 component input with specific values

Tags: angular

Hello i have a simple question. My component has one input and i would like to specified how values can be inserted.

```
export class MyComponent{
  @Input() type: string; //only active, disable...
}
```

It is possible to say to input how values is valid? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use an [Enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html), but I think the best way is to use a switch case or conditions in your `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to validate the input value in property `setter`

```
 export class MyComponent{
      private _type: string; //only active, disable...


        get type(): string{
            return this._type;
        }

        @Input() set type(value: string) {
            if(['active', 'disable'].indexOf(value) !== -1) 
              this._type = value;
            else
              // take action        
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use enums

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Do something like:

```
enum State {
    Active,
    Disabled
}
```

And on the component

```
@Input() type: State;
```